# GitLab CE behind router (port forwarding)

Tags: gitlab

I want to have a gitlab running on my local machine.

I have ha dynamic DNS pointing to my router and a port is forwarded to the 
local machine.

If I do not set the `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` everything works fine, besides the wrong links are displayed in the browser.

If I set it to the address which is used to reach the gitlab  (e.g. `example.com:8888`), I cannot connect.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you forwarding 8888 to 8888 on your machine, or are you using different internal and external ports?

Comment: To 80, does the port of the external URL change the port where the web app is running?

Comment: By default yes, it sets the nginx port. But you can set it seperately as well. `nginx['listen_port']'  seen here: http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html

Comment: Ah, thx. Does not matter to me. I will try to change one of them

Comment: Using external_url='example.com:8888' and `nginx['listen_port']` = 80 works. Thanks. You may provide this as an answer ;)